# apt-get update fails on Ubuntu 16.04 when I enable the google music manager ppa

Tags: apt, ppa, 16.04

Seems as if the pre-16.04 security key security is no longer sufficient. I'm not sure what to do to fix this. Or is this something google needs to fix on their end?

```
moorepants@parvati:~$ sudo aptitude update
Hit http://mirror.math.ucdavis.edu/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit http://mirror.math.ucdavis.edu/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                       
Hit http://mirror.math.ucdavis.edu/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                             
Hit http://mirror.math.ucdavis.edu/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                              
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                       
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable InRelease        
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                
Get: 1 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable Release [1,345 B]
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get: 2 http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb stable Release.gpg [198 B]
Fetched 1,543 B in 0s (2,637 B/s)                            
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key <KEY> uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key <KEY> uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/dists/stable/Release: No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_musicmanager_deb_dists_stable_Release which is considered strong enough for security purposes
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Something Google needs to fix. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272200/apt-update-failed-on-debian-linux